# How to add button in toolstrip on left and right side

Tags: smartgwt

Its possible add buttons in toolstrip on left and right side, as image below show.

I try add css style but its not possible add style on image div.

PS. I create that effect using firebug.

[image: Buttons in toolstrip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [LayoutSpacer](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/LayoutSpacer.html).

```
ToolStrip toolStrip = new ToolStrip();
...
toolStrip.setMembers(leftBtn1, leftBtn2, new LayoutSpacer(), rightBtn1, rightBtn2);
```

That will align first two buttons to left and other two buttons to right.